# C++: why output iterators do not support comparison operations?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I've read that except output iterators, all the other categories of iterators support at least == and != operators.

Why do the output iterators not support this?

Comment: Why would you want to compare an output iterator?

Comment: What would be the "end of output" that you need to compare to.  Output iterators just write data out.

Comment: @SergeyA, i'm just looking at each iterator type's capabilities, if I can't then I won't (which is the case here). But if I know why it is not allowed then I'll try to avoid such circumstances.

Comment: @NathanOliver, do you mean that once i increment the output iterator i can't access the previous element ?

Comment: @pasha, yes, this is the whole property if output iterators

Comment: one thing that seems logical is, you can't compare if you can't access (since i can't access elements with output iterators it is not allowed). could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes.  Lets say you're writing data out to a tape.  The tape can grow and grow (lets assume infinite storage).  What would you ever need to compare the current byte your outputting to the tape?  You can't go backwards (the reel is only guaranteed to go one way) so you never need to check something behind you and there is no end so there is nothing in front that needs to be checked either.  All you do is write and increment.

Comment: Are you thinking of smart output iterators?

Comment: @NathanOliver, ok so my earlier comment providing logic to why it isn't allowed is wrong. As SergeyA commented on the answer that Neil Gatenby provided.

Comment: just to provide an example case of what i'm thinking. If I maintain two output iterators i1, i2 both pointing to begin() of container and if I write to i1 and increment i1, what happens to i2? I don't understand why the comparison of i1 and i2 is not allowed.

Comment: What are those iterators iterating? (in other words, how they were created?)

Comment: @SergeyA, I'm not sure how it would affect, but lets say from a vector.begin()

Comment: vector iterators can be used as more than just output iterators (they are random access iterators), so does this restriction even apply to what you're doing?

Comment: @Kevin, if not vector then something that supports only output iterator (i haven't encountered any so I cannot provide more than this but you get what i'm trying to say, right?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison of `i1` and `i2` **isn't forbidden**. `std::vector::iterator` *is* `OutputIterator`, and you can compare them. What you can't do is that *assume that all* `OutputIterator`s can be compared.

All the concept is saying is that it **isn't required** for a type to support comparison for it to be an `OutputIterator`, because requiring it would mean some things that really do deserve to be `OutputIterator`s aren't. An example would be [@NathanOliver's tape iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770075/c-why-output-iterators-do-not-support-comparison-operations#comment96320509_54770075). Another example is [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)

We already have the situation where one of the Iterator categories has an overly burdensome requirement: `ForwardIterator` requires that dereferencing return a reference type. This means that any proxy iterator is limited to `InputIterator`, even if it supports `--`, `+=`, `-=` etc.

If you find yourself writing multiple functions that want to write until they have "filled" an output, you might consider defining a category `ComparableOutputIterator` (or somesuch name), and require `==` as well as `OutputIterator` for membership of that category.

Comment: makes sense, any reason why this logic isn't applied for input iterators?

Comment: @pasha Because deciding when to stop based on where you are reading from is much more common. Look at all the algorithms that have pairs of iterators for input, but only a single iterator for output.

Comment: makes perfect sense again, for algorithms that accept output iterators, it is assumed that wherever (a container or similar) out is from has enough storage. So, it doesn't need second one supplied. @Caleth thank you